# Can you create multiple indexes on a single field in Mongo? What does that look like?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-ruby, nosql

I'm trying to create a compound key as my "_id" field, which takes in some geo information as well as other attributes.  It looks something like:

```
{_id: {lat: 50, lon: 50, name: "some name"}}
```

After creating the document, mongo assigns an index by default, and ignores my command

```
db.coll.ensureIndex(_id: "2d")
```

Is there a way to do this so I can have my _id field index-able by both geo-index and regular index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. Both of them require a change in your schema:

1. Make `_id` a unique hash and put your coordinates in a separate field with a 2d index:

   {_id: "standard ObjectId or your hash", name: "some name", loc: [50, 50]}
2. If you really want _id to be the only field (I wouldn't recommend this):

   {_id: {name: "some name", loc: [50, 50]}}

   db.coll.ensureIndex({'_id.loc': '2d'})

Answer (score 0):

From the MongoDB documentation:

> Users are welcome to use their own conventions for creating ids; the _id value may be of any type, other than arrays, so long as it is a unique. Arrays are not allowed because they are Multikeys.

You would also have to ensure these are unique too.  Also this will mess with some things that presume you have a BSON ID

I would just index those fields on their own and make a compound index.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs